# Filtering fields to display, what about nested ones?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch 6.X, I use the following command to display specific fields from a query

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/_search?stored_fields=_id
```

What about nested fields? For documents like this,

```
{
    "data": {
         "field1": "hello"
    }
}
```

If I want to display only data.field1, what command should I use? The following one doesn't work:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/_search?stored_fields=data.field1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html), you can achieve what you want

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/_search?_source=data.field1
```